# javascript function on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which prints bar code and I want to make a click event, but when I am calling my function using javascript on click, its not working, please find the code below?
I am able to view it on page without onclick. I want to call get_object(id)

Comment: You are missing an "=" after "onclick"

Answer (score 5):

If you copy-pasted it, you first need to change

```
onclick "get_object("110091")"
```

To

```
onclick="get_object('110091')"
```

You forgot the **=** sign, and you can not use double quotes " inside an attribute value (since they are already used for separating it)

Answer (score 3):

your missing the = sign it should be onclick="get..."

Answer (score 2):

Is your post mistyped, or is the "=" after "onclick" actually missing?
Also, you should use single-quote inside the get_object() method, or this will not properly parse.

Answer (score 1):

Your tag needs to read:

```
... onclick="get_object('110091')" ...
```

note both the equals sign, and using the alternate quote characters inside - as it is your use of double quotes both to enclose the attribute and to pass the function parameter will break.

Also, why use such a complicated `get_object()` function?  Your question is tagged `HTML5` which AFAIK guarantees that `getElementById()` will be available.

Comment: i m using html 5 I just want to call that function, I have change the code above and also here below:<button type="button" button data-theme="b" onclick="get_object(id)">theater</button> Not working dude

Answer (score 0):

Your get_object function does nothing but return the DOM object using the id passed in - it doesn't draw any barcodes... It sounds to me like you want:

```
<button type="button" button data-theme="b" id="submit" onclick="DrawCode39Barcode(get_object('inputdata').innerHTML,0);return false;">theater</button>
```